# Divide irregular polygon into hexagons

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm working on an engineering project, i was asked to divide an irregular polygon into (n) hexagonals like in this image:

[image]

would like to know if there is an algorithm for distribution ?

Comment: What do you mean by "like the one in this image"? The hexagonals need to be regular and of the same size?

Comment: yes they will be of same size and they should be covering the whole area of the polygon, the area of the hexagonal is given

Comment: Well, your question is not still clear to me. But, a potential simple algorithm would be to cover the whole area of the polygon and a bit more from the edges by the hexagonals (e.g., inside the bounding rectangle). Then iterate over the hexagonals and remove the ones that are not inside the polygon. You could edit your question and add more details to it, specially the format of the input/output required.

Comment: Okay you got me right but I need an answer that could be implemented using java code .. I'm posting it in the right place ?

Comment: @Smartdog I think you just got an algorithm that could be implemented (by you) in Java.  Now that you have an algorithm if you need coding help you could try StackOverflow.com

Comment: @Smartdog: No, here is not the right place. But, I think it's straightforward to implement the algorithm I proposed. If you want to code in Java, there is a *java.awt.Polygon* class which is helpful in this case. It has methods to get the bounding box of the polygon and test if a given point is inside it or not. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

Comment: @Mohsen you got me right, I'm good at java and have all my utilities in hand, but was asking of the approach to locate the spots, one approach may be to begin with the center and spread, another may be start from any edge and loop inside, you have any idea if there is any recommended approach ??

Comment: @Smartdog: i would say starting from a corner is simpler to implement. I would even start a bit before the corner to make sure every point inside the polygon is covered. I mean if say `(minX, minY)` is the top left corner of the bounding box, I would start the tiling from `(minX-W/2, minY-H/2)`, where `W` and `H` are the width and height of the hexagons. Then you can remove the ones that are not required.

Comment: @Mohsen Thank you I will try this strategy .. any way there will be optimization phase where I will try different strategies